# sun gridengine error "shepherd of job 119232.1 exited with exit status = 26"

Tags: queue, sungridengine

We use gridengine(extactly open grid scheduler 2011.11.p1) as batch-queuing system. Just now I added an execd host named `host094`, but when jobs were submitted there, errors issued, status of job is `Eqw`,  logs in `$SGE_ROOT/default/spool/host094/messages` says:

```
shepherd of job 119232.1 exited with exit status = 26
can't open usage file active_jobs/119232.1/usage for job 119232.1: No such file or directory
```

What's the meaning?